# Is it possible to copy public ssh keys from other users to a remote server when users have no access yet?

Tags: ssh

How to copy the public ssh keys from other users to to their ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on a remote server?

I'm aware of the 'ssh-copy-id' command, but I assume it only work if the user has currently normal access via their password on the remote computer. I could copy the files with SCP to my own directory, then login and copy the the files to the users directory, but I would like to have a method that does not involve extra handling on the remote server.

- Only ssh password-less-login is allowed (None of the users are allowed to login with password
- Currently one user (me) has password-less-login access and has 'sudo' rights
- Assume other users don't have a '~/.ssh' directory

local client:  MacOs X

remote server: Debian

Comment: Upload, move, change owner, set permissions.  Are you looking for someone to write a script for you?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to write a script.

There is a sshd configuration parameter called `AuthorizedKeysFile` by default is is set to `.ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2`

You could create user specific keys is /etc/sshd/authorized_keys.%u

Example:
`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/authorized_keys.%u .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2
```

Then you create /etc/ssh/authorize_keys.pyther. You would put my public key in the file. When I log in, I would use my private key.